# How to programmatically specify multiple iterators?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

How to use `Row[Table[{B[i],0,i},{i,0,2}],","]` directly in `Do` command? I mean that the following command

```
Row[Table[{B[i],0,i},{i,0,2}],","]
```

gives

```
{B[0], 0, 0},{B[1], 0, 1},{B[2],0,2}
```

But, the following command returns the error

> "Do::nliter: Non-list iterator Row[Table[{B[i], 0, i}, {i, 0, 2}], ,] at position 2 does not evaluate to a real numeric value."

```
Do[Print[B[0]+B[1]+B[2]],Row[Table[{B[i],0,i},{i,0,2}],","]]
```

Of course, one can type instead by hand the following:

```
Do[Print[B[0]+B[1]+B[2]],{B[0],0,0},{B[1],0,1},{B[2],0,2}]
```

But, I feel that typing an output by hand again is not really an optimal method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you actually want is to create a `Sequence` from the `Table` to be used as your iterators.

You can do this with

```
Do[Print[B[0] + B[1] + B[2]], Sequence @@ Table[{B[i], 0, i}, {i, 0, 2}] // 
Evaluate]

(*0
  1
  2
  1
  2
  3*)
```

Or, so you don't have to force evaluation,

```
Do[Print[B[0] + B[1] + B[2]], ##] & @@ Table[{B[i], 0, i}, {i, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: The second one is my favorite way to deal with multiple autogenerated iterators.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can avoid [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do) and instead use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples):

```
Tuples @ Range[0, {0, 1, 2}]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2}}

You can then use [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total) to sum each tuple:

```
Total[
    Tuples @ Range[0, {0, 1, 2}],
    {2}
]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3}

Answer (score 5):

```
Do[Print[B[0] + B[1] + B[2]], 
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ First@ Row[Table[{B[i], 0, i}, {i, 0, 2}], ","]]]
```

or

```
row = Row[Table[{B[i], 0, i}, {i, 0, 2}], ","];
Do[Print[B[0] + B[1] + B[2]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ row[[1]]]]
```